# Не работает react production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, build, create-react-app

Делаю проект с фронтом на React и бэком на Express (связывалось при помощи добавления "proxy" в package.json клиента). В dev-режиме все работает как надо. Решил попробовать захостить проект. Для этого выполнил "npm run build", а в server.js дописал:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'))
});
```

(Вот структура проекта)

[image: строение проекта]

Но работает не так как должно.
Пример как было при разработке(так должно работать):

[image: режим разработки]

вот что получается на деле:

[image: продакшн]

то бишь не работают либо какие-то скрипты. И вот такие ошибки выдает консоль:

[image: консоль Хрома]

Первый раз делаю production build, поэтому даже не понимаю в чем ошибка и вообще правильно ли я делаю. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: прилетел html вместо json; смотрите что внутри "network"

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov спасибо, сам я бы не скоро додумался посмотреть именно туда! действительно, мне на все обращения к бэку API отправлял только сам файл index.js. и все что нужно было сделать это в `app.get('*', ... ` поставить не звездочку, а слэш. теперь все работает как надо!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov извиняюсь, но у меня возникла новая проблема и хотел спросить- может вы знаете что нужно делать. Ситуация такая: если заходить на сайт с основной страницы "/"  то все работает хорошо, все переходы между страницами осуществляются при помощи react router. Но вот в чем беда: если в адресной строке набрать "localhost:3000/books", то он просто выкинет сырой json.

Comment: с обычным роутером не делал; у меня роут после `#`, который на сервер не идет; мне хватает; наверно есть какие-то минусы (сео или еще что), не знаю